# Python package exploring (urllib) (Windows) (Python3.9.6)

Tags: python, module, package

While exploring 'urllib' i've stumbled upon these:

1. dir(urllib) doesn't seem to contain 'request', although it is imported as "urllib.request". When it is imported as such and dir(urllib) is performed again, the contents now are urllib's + request's.
2. help(urllib) returns "'more' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable or batch file" (ftr, inside Python, not cmd, and it happens regardless of having already imported urllib.request);

About 1), without reading tutorials or docs, how is one supposed to know of 'request' (or any other possible feature) since it doesn't show inside the contents of its parent module?

As of 2), I'm clueless.

Code:

```
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> help(urllib)
'more' não é reconhecido como um comando interno        
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'parse']
>>> import urllib.request
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response']
>>>
```